# Input range won't work in an scrollable div when you simulate a smartphone

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

I have an `input range` in a `div` contained in an outer `div` that is smaller than the inner `div`. The final result is that my inner `div` scrolls horizontally (because the outer dive has `overflow: scroll`), and the `input range` is its child.

To customize the range, I removed the appearance in CSS with `appearance: none`. Now, here is what happens. When I check it in Chrome developer's tool (actually I use Brave, but I'm guessing it is the same in Chrome as I tested in Chromium, and it is the same) with the smartphone option active, 99% of the time if I try to move the range handle it moves the whole `div` with it. Now, if I disable the smartphone option, it works just fine. Also, if I keep the smartphone option and remove the `appearance: none` from CSS, it also works just fine, but my customizations to the range disappear. Does anyone know what is going on?

PS.: in Firefox, the `input range` doesn't work as long as I keep the smartphone option on (no matter if I have the appearance property or not).

Here is an animated gif of what I mean:
First, I have the described above with the `input range` with no appearance. It works fine, I can move the scrollable `div` and move the `input range` handle independently. Then I put the `appearance: none` to the `input range` (notice the formatting of the input range changes), now I can't move the `input range` handle independently from the scrollable `div` anymore. Finally, remove the appearance from the `input range`, and everything goes back to normal (but my customizations are gone)
[image: Text]

Here is the code, but you can only simulate by using the developer's tool with the smartphone option active, where you can simulate the touch.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    #outerframe {
      height: 310px;
      width: 300px;
      border: 2px solid red;
      padding: 8px;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: scroll;
    }

    #scrollarea {
      height: 300px;
      width: 400px;
      border: 1px dashed green;
      padding: 16px;
    }

    input[type=range] {
      appearance: none;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #aaa, #ccf1ff 30%, #ccf1ff 70%, #aaa);
      outline: none;
      opacity: 0.7;
      border-radius: 4px;
      height: 14px;
      width: 200px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, 0 -5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin: 16px;
    }

    input[type=text] {
      width: 50px;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Testing range in scroll</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="outerframe">
    <div id="scrollarea">
      <input type="range" id="rangescroll">
      <input type="text" value="50">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    scrollarea.firstElementChild.addEventListener('input', evt => {
      evt.target.nextElementSibling.value = evt.target.value;
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
FIX:

Oleg Barabanov, suggested to make the `overflow: hidden` while moving the input handle (add a class for that on [touchstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) and removing the class on [touchend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)). While that works I thought about a more elegant solution. I remembered about [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) and how it allows us to cancel browser handling of subsequent events. The idea was, if I can allow one event, the `input` event and block the rest (the scrolling event done by the browser automatically) then it could work.

This is the additional code I first tried for the input range:

```
    document.querySelector('.scrollarea').firstElementChild.addEventListener("touchstart", (evt) =>

document.querySelector('.outerframe').classList.add("overflow-hidden");
      evt.preventDefault();
    });
```

It didn't work here (which is surprising for me as I successfully used that in the past to stop default events). But then I remembered that when I studied JS events there was another way to prevent default events and that was to [return false for the event](https://javascript.info/default-browser-action#preventing-browser-actions):

```
    document.querySelector('.scrollarea').firstElementChild.addEventListener("touchstart", (evt) =>

document.querySelector('.outerframe').classList.add("overflow-hidden");
      return false;
    });
```

To be fair, that article mentions that `return false` would only work for when the event is configured as an attribute like `ontouchstart`. But I used with the `addEventListener()` method and it also worked.

I hope it helps more people in the future.

Comment: Usually when this happens, it is becuase of browser support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not the best solution, but it seems to work. Just using the `touchstart` and `touchend` events + css `overflow`:

```js
scrollarea.firstElementChild.addEventListener("input", (evt) => {
  evt.target.nextElementSibling.value = evt.target.value;
});
scrollarea.firstElementChild.addEventListener("touchstart", (evt) => {
  outerframe.classList.add("overflow-hidden");
});
scrollarea.firstElementChild.addEventListener("touchend", (evt) => {
  outerframe.classList.remove("overflow-hidden");
});
```

```css
#outerframe {
  height: 310px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#scrollarea {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px dashed green;
  padding: 16px;
}

input[type=range] {
  appearance: none;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #aaa, #ccf1ff 30%, #ccf1ff 70%, #aaa);
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, 0 -5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 16px;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 50px;
}

.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden !important;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Testing range in scroll</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="outerframe">
    <div id="scrollarea">
      <input type="range" id="rangescroll">
      <input type="text" value="50">
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't believe you suggest such a horrible workaround, and I can't believe how much I loved it lol. You are right, if I make the overflow hidden as I move the handle it solves the problem, but that got me thinking... I remembered I studied some time ago about preventDefault. So I thought, instead of making the overflow hidden, I should prevent the browser handling of the event. To be honest it didnt quite work with preventDefault (for some reason) so I used the other approach which is to return false in the input touchstart event, and that works like a charm. I'm editing the post with that...

Comment: Your workaround made me think about a more elegant solution, so I'm selecting it as the right one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me exactly why, but when you are in the mobile test view, disabling the `height` and `width` from `#scrollarea` in dev tools fixes the problem. The `#scrollarea` in the mobile view is handled by moving everything within the parameters.
Two other solutions, which avoid having to remove your parameters are setting `position=fixed` or `position=absolute` on `#rangescroll`.

Comment: Can also be brwser support?? Because I don't see any prefixed properties in his css

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Aleksey. In fact, by removing the height and width from #scrollarea you are removing the ability to scroll that div in the outer frame, that is why you are under the impression that the problem was fixed. I need the scroll area to be larger than the #outerframe (thus making the scrollarea indeed scrollable) but I need that area to remain fixed when I'm moving the input handle. As for changing the position of #rangescroll, that only makes the input fixed on the viewport. Even if I make the scrollable area as position relative, the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a problem with browser support, you can try online tools that can help in generating CSS code with cross browser support.
So I would recommend you can go [here](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)

Here is the code that was generated:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    #outerframe {
      height: 310px;
      width: 300px;
      border: 2px solid red;
      padding: 8px;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
    
    #scrollarea {
      height: 300px;
      width: 400px;
      border: 1px dashed green;
      padding: 16px;
    }
    
    input[type=range] {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#aaa), color-stop(30%, #ccf1ff), color-stop(70%, #ccf1ff), to(#aaa));
      background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #aaa, #ccf1ff 30%, #ccf1ff 70%, #aaa);
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #aaa, #ccf1ff 30%, #ccf1ff 70%, #aaa);
      outline: none;
      opacity: 0.7;
      border-radius: 4px;
      height: 14px;
      width: 200px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, 0 -5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
      box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, 0 -5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin: 16px;
    }
    
    input[type=text] {
      width: 50px;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Testing range in scroll</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="outerframe">
    <div id="scrollarea">
      <input type="range" id="rangescroll">
      <input type="text" value="50">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    scrollarea.firstElementChild.addEventListener('input', evt => {
      evt.target.nextElementSibling.value = evt.target.value;
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if you try the code on Chrome you will see that the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the css property `touch-action:manipulation;` to your `#outerframe` to disable touch events from it when in smartphone mode

edit: I figured out that `touch-action:manipulation;` might not solve it but `touch-action:none` will but in expense of rendering `overflow:scroll;` useless in mobile

2nd edit: I figure out adding `touch-action: pan-x; touch-action: pan-y` instead of `touch-action:none;` cant still make your outer div scrollable in a certain way

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    #outerframe {
      height: 310px;
      width: 300px;
      border: 2px solid red;
      padding: 8px;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: scroll;
    touch-action: pan-x;
    touch-action: pan-y;
    }

    #scrollarea {
      height: 300px;
      width: 400px;
      border: 1px dashed green;
      padding: 16px;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    }

    input[type=range] {
      appearance: none;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #aaa, #ccf1ff 30%, #ccf1ff 70%, #aaa);
      outline: none;
      opacity: 0.7;
      border-radius: 4px;
      height: 14px;
      width: 200px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, 0 -5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin: 16px;
    }

    input[type=text] {
      width: 50px;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Testing range in scroll</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="outerframe">
    <div id="scrollarea">
      <input type="range" id="rangescroll">
      <input type="text" value="50">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    scrollarea.firstElementChild.addEventListener('input', evt => {
      evt.target.nextElementSibling.value = evt.target.value;
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is right. Unfortunately it will disable the scroll and I need that. By the way, some people above suggested removing height and width or making overflow hidden. All of them disables scroll and breaks my code.

Answer (score -1):

In mobile you drag to scroll up and down, as well left and right. If you would just disable the `overflow-x` on `#outerframe` you can fix your problem:

```css
    #outerframe {
      height: 310px;
      width: 300px;
      border: 2px solid red;
      padding: 8px;
      margin: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    #scrollarea {
      height: 300px;
      width: 400px;
      border: 1px dashed green;
      padding: 16px;
    }

    input[type=range] {
      appearance: none;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #aaa, #ccf1ff 30%, #ccf1ff 70%, #aaa);
      outline: none;
      opacity: 0.7;
      border-radius: 4px;
      height: 14px;
      width: 200px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, 0 -5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin: 16px;
    }

    input[type=text] {
      width: 50px;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="outerframe">
    <div id="scrollarea">
      <input type="range" id="rangescroll">
      <input type="text" value="50">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    scrollarea.firstElementChild.addEventListener('input', evt => {
      evt.target.nextElementSibling.value = evt.target.value;
    })
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By having overlow-x: hidden on the #outerframe defeats the whole purpose for the case. I want it to be scrollable so I can have a big div inside and move horizontally to reach other components, but the inputs inside, when their handles are moved, this div (#scrollarea) should not move